# RestEasy JAXB - expose third party classes in XML

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, marshalling, resteasy

I'm new both to RestEasy and JAXB. I think they're pretty easy to use as far as you control all the sources you want to expose via a web service.

But now I have a problem. I have data transfer objects that I cannot (should not) annotate with JAXB annotations but I still want them to marshal to XML.

What is the easiest way or the best practice to do so?

Any help or comment is appreciated.

Balázs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I got fetched entity objects (already with real data) from the persistence layer, but they were from 3rd party classes, which I couldn't annotate with `@XmlRootElement`, nor change the fetching code.

To me, simply wrapping them in `JAXBElement` did the trick. So, the RESTful method:

```
@GET
@Path("/listAll")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML); // "application/xml"
public List<Person> getPersonList() {
   return persistenceLayer.fetchAllPerson();
}
```

Worked when changed to:

```
@GET
@Path("/listAll")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML); // "application/xml"
public List<JAXBElement<Person>> getPersonList() {
   List<Person> ps = persistenceLayer.fetchAllPerson();
   List<JAXBElement<Person>> jaxbeps = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Person>>(ps.size());
   for (Person p : ps) {
       jaxbeps.add(jaxbeWrapp(p));
   }
   return jaxbeps;
}
```

and the generic method used (you can just inline it, of course):

```
public  static <T> JAXBElement<T> jaxbeWrapp(T obj) {
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)  obj.getClass();
    return new JAXBElement<T>(new QName(obj.getClass().getName().toLowerCase()), clazz, obj);
}
```

That's it! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use MOXy's mapping document JAXB extension to provide the metadata.  Then you could use a `ContextResolver` in JAX-RS to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

```
package blog.bindingfile.jaxrs;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

import blog.bindingfile.Customer;

@Provider
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public class CustomerContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext jc;

    public CustomerContextResolver() {
        ClassLoader cl = Customer.class.getClassLoader();
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        props.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "blog/bindingfile/binding.xml");
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Customer.class} , props);
   }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(Customer.class == clazz) {
            return jc;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**For a Detailed Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html

Comment: thanks, I'll try this as soon as have time for it. this looks like exactly what I was looking for.